# How to skip third step and jump to fourth step

Tags: vue.js

Here I have written code in vue.js. And I am trying to skip third step to fourth step. Like we we are navigating multistep form and we are at second step and from second step if we press next button then it should directly navigate to fourth step. means skipping third step. So I am trying to achieve this if any one Have an idea please help me

```
<div id="app">
  <form>
  <div v-if="step === 1">

    <h1>Step One</h1>
    <p>
    <legend for="name">Your Name:</legend>
    <input id="name" name="name" v-model="registration.name">
    </p>

    <p>
    <legend for="email">Your Email:</legend>
    <input id="email" name="email" type="email" v-model="registration.email">
    </p>

    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>
    
  </div>

  <div v-if="step === 2">
    <h1>Step Two</h1>
    <p>
    <legend for="street">Your Street:</legend>
    <input id="street" name="street" v-model="registration.street">
    </p>

    <p>
    <legend for="city">Your City:</legend>
    <input id="city" name="city" v-model="registration.city">
    </p>

    <p>
    <legend for="state">Your State:</legend>
    <input id="state" name="state" v-model="registration.state">
    </p>

    <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>

  </div>

  <div v-if="step === 3">
    <h1>Step Three</h1>
    
    <p>
    <legend for="numtickets">Number of Tickets:</legend>
    <input id="numtickets" name="numtickets" type="number" v-model="registration.numtickets">
    </p>

    <p>
    <legend for="shirtsize">Shirt Size:</legend>
    <select id="shirtsize" name="shirtsize" v-model="registration.shirtsize">
      <option value="S">Small</option>
      <option value="M">Medium</option>
      <option value="L">Large</option>
      <option value="XL">X-Large</option>
    </select>
    </p>

    <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>  
    
  </div>
  
  <div v-if="step === 4">
    <h1>Step Four</h1>
    <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
    <button @click.prevent="next()">Next</button>

  </div>
  
  <div v-if="step === 5">
    <h1>Step Five</h1>
    <button @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
    <button @click.prevent="submit()">Save</button>

  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

**vue.js**

```
<script>
const app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data() {
    return {
      step:1,
      registration:{
        name:null,
        email:null,
        street:null,
        city:null,
        state:null,
        numtickets:0,
        shirtsize:'XL'
      }
    }
  },
  methods:{
    prev() {
      this.step--;
    },
    next() {
      this.step++;
    },
    submit() {
      alert('Submit to blah and show blah and etc.');      
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily achieve it by assigning the desired page with:

```js
this.step = 4 // or another site you want to set
```

pass an argument in the `next()` function:

```html
<button @click.prevent="next(3)">Next</button>
```

```js
next(currentStep) {
 if (currentStep === 3) {
     this.step = 4 // jump from step 2 to step 4
  } else {
     this.step++;
  }
}
```

as a quick suggestion

update to navigate back:

```html
<button @click.prevent="prev(4)">Previous</button>
```

```js
prev(currentStep) {
 if (currentStep === 4) {
     this.step = 2 // jump from step 4 to step 2
  } else {
     this.step--
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Wittgenstein. The solution is working and it is helping me a lot.

Comment: Hi sir. the solution is working fine but while we navigate back using previous button then it is displaying third step. It should not display

Comment: updated may answer. it's the same way - only vice versa.